# Is there any simple way to copy an uchar array to a double array?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I have an simple array **[not vector]** of data ranging between 0-255 in a uchar type array. But for some computation I need to copy the array to a double type array.

I can do that by a loop and copying it element by element. But looking if there is an easy process to do this by some function or methods.

Comment: It really depends on how you intend to convert your bytes to doubles. There's no single way to do that. You might want to look at `memcpy` however, it might do what you need.

Comment: It might help if you posted your 'copying it element by element' code. Then it would be clearer what you are trying to achieve,

Comment: I'd suggest `std::copy` or `std::transform` depending on how you want to convert values from char to double.

Comment: C or C++? The answer will differ fundamentally depending on the language.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I am doing it in C++11

Comment: @KonradRudolph Even in C++, it is not always a `std::vector` by any means (even in C++ containers, `std::array` for example has no such constructor). `std::copy` or similar solutions are more general.

Comment: @FireLancer yes and I am using an simple array thats the issue.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I checked the question but there is nothing mentioned for a simple array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[C++ algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) work on any type of iterator, they are not restricted to specific container types.

As such, you can use [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to copy values from one iterator range to another, and perform implicit type conversion in the process:

```
uchar a[N];
double b[N];
// …
std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(b));
// or:
std::copy_n(std::begin(a), N, std::begin(b));
```

The above uses a C-style array but the same of course works with `std::array`.

Comment: It's throwing this error. `variable-sized array type ‘long int’ is not a valid template argument`

Comment: @KousikMitra How is your array declared? Standard C++ has nothing called “variable-sized array” (these exist as non-standard extensions and shouldn’t be used). It sounds like you should use a vector after all.

Comment: Thanks. I have used a vector after all and its working fine. Actually I am working with nvcc compiler may be that is the problem with a normal array.